# Flutter: Keypad Number with Options not showing on Android Device, only on Emulator.

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Keypad on Emulator executes correctly, Keypad on Android device doesn't show the extended keypad, only shows number only keypad. 
Any ideas why would same code would execute different?

-----Keypad on emulator------

[image]

```
   new TextFormField(
           keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
```

-----Keypad on Android Device------

[image]

Comment: Looks like the keyboard you're using on the physical device doesn't support the extended number pad format. Is it a stock manufacturer keyboard?

Comment: @ReverseCold stock keyboard,  reproduced the issue on LG mobile phone and Samsung Tablet, same results.

Comment: Right, but the manufacturers can put their own different stock keyboard. Maybe try another app that you know for sure opens up the extended window? If that doesn't work then you might need to implement your own keyboard.

Comment: @ReverseCold Its a Make and model issue, Tested on a newer Samsung and keyboard works. thanks for the comments

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)